# How to Read Query Filters from Within a LoopBack Model

Tags: model, loopbackjs, strongloop

We're using LoopBack for our REST APIs and need to access the query filter (that was specified in the client) from within custom logic in the LoopBack model. For example, given this query:

```
http://localhost:1337/api/Menus/formatted?filter[where][id]=42
```

how would we access the 'where' parameter from within the 'Menu.formatted' code:

```
function asMenu(Menu) {
    Menu.formatted = function (callback) {

        <<Need to access the query filter here...>>
```

Comment: Specifically, we need to access the query filter in custom functions from within LoopBack in addition to the standard, built-in CRUD functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare `filter` query paramerter as argument for your `formatted` remote method and then access it just like `callback` argument.

See how to [describe arguments in docs](http://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Remote+methods#Remotemethods-Registeringaremotemethod).

Answer (score 4):

A way to introduce a filter should be something similar to this :

```
module.exports = function(Menu) {
    Menu.formatted = function (filter,callback) {
      // Your code here
    }
    Menu.remoteMethod('formatted', {
      http: { path: '/formatted', verb: 'get' },
      accepts: [
        { arg: 'filter', type: 'object', 'http': { source: 'query' } }
      ],
      returns: { type: 'object', root: true }
    });
};
```

In the example above, in the `accepts` field, which represents arguments that the remote method receives, you need to add the `filter` argument. This way you can use `filter`'s query parameter value as an object.